# Update form after ajax save

Tags: yii2

I want form data updated after ajax save. Cause if item was new (id - empty), it tries to create new one each time. Also there are back-end generated fields which are appears after save.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'method' => 'post',
        'action' => ['category/save', 'id' => $category ? $category->id : ''],
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
//        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'validateOnChange' => false,
        'validateOnBlur' => false,
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'options' => [
            'id' => 'customer-update',
            'class' => 'ajax-submit',
        ],
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => '<div class="row-content-col1">{label}</div><div class="row-content-col2">{input}{error}</div>'
        ]
    ]); ?>
.......

<?php echo $form->field($category, 'url')->textInput(['class' => 'ip', 'readonly' => true]); ?>

......

<?php $form->end(); ?>
```

Form field produce such html:

```
<div class="row-content-col1"><label class="control-label" for="category-url">Url</label></div><div class="row-content-col2"><input type="text" id="category-url" class="ip" name="Category[url]" readonly><div class="help-block"></div></div>
</div>
```

And than on controller i return this (tried different variations):

```
{"error":false,"message":"Category 'asdfzsdf sdf' saved","data":{"name":"asdfzsdf sdf","url":"asdfzsdf-sdf","project_id":1,"id":21}}
```

What is valid response for ajax form? Or is there other way to handle this all ?

Comment: You want form to submit data, after save, change form to update that data, Did I understand question?

Comment: @ttrasn data submission works fine. i can not understand how to get data to the form after submit. so there should appear "id" value for example

Comment: You can use Pjax, which I described in my answer ;)

Comment: @ttrasn no other ideas ?

Comment: You can create html elements with php and send it via json response to view. and then insert it in form parent box, but is not my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Pjax is really useful for your challenge, Just add your form inside of Pjax widget. add form action to new path(such: site/control-data).
In your action method do what you want, but send response like that :

```
return $this->renderAjax('form path',$model);
```

It's the general of what you must do.
But maybe you have problem with jquery or pjax or need some more data, but all questions have an answer,

See [Pjax for ActiveForm](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2)